# R find all indexes of character matches in a list of strings

Tags: r, string, indexing, match

I have a df like this (with ~800,000 lines)

```
 #    str

   # 1  .||.

   # 2  .

   # 3  .|..

   # 4  ..
```

and I want a new data frame like this (record the location in each character string with a `.`) (sorry about the formatting of columns)

```
#   str     loc

   # 1  .||.    1 4

   # 2  .       1

   # 3  .|..    1 3 4

   # 4  ..      1 2
```

I can get the locations with `gregexpr(".", str, fixed = TRUE)`, but I don’t know how to get the first part of the `gregexpr` output, without the three attribute parts. I will later use the location vectors in other calculations. As `gregexpr` is vectorized, I do not want to use a loop to do this, as this would take too long. I think this problem must have been addressed in previous questions, but I can’t find a solution. Also, if there is a completely different way to handle this, please tell me.

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example Try with `library(stringr);str_locate_all(".||.", fixed("."))[[1]][,1]`

Comment: unlist works for one line, but when applied to the entire list, it does not preserve the line information.

Comment: str_locate_all seems to work fine. Seems that there should be a simple gregexpr solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. Is this what you mean?

```
S = c("appleap", "tapppapp")
P = "ap"

lapply(gregexpr(P, S), function(x) as.vector(x))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 6

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 6
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked fine too.  Comparing the str_locate_all and the lapply approach for ~30,000 records, I found  > start_time <- Sys.time()
> xxx <- str_locate_all(bio$blast.mid.var, "[.]")
> end_time <- Sys.time()
> end_time - start_time
Time difference of 0.03490591 secs
> 
> start_time <- Sys.time()
> xxx <- lapply(bio$blast.mid.var, function(x) unlist(gregexpr(".", x)))
> end_time <- Sys.time()
> end_time - start_time
Time difference of 0.2782559 secs
> 
As long as the lapply method is not O(n2), it should work for larger datasets too.  I will need to check time complexity

Comment: So I checked time complexity. str_locate_all is O(n) and lapply is O(n2).